# D3 scatterplot click to push and splice data and update the DOM behaves erratically

Tags: d3.js

This is my first real d3 project and I'm trying to create an interactive learning experience for those learning statistics. I am trying to create an interactive scatterplot where the user can click on the plot to add a data point, then click on a data point to remove it.  Both actions should update the data set, update the DOM, and update an r value and line which is visible on the plot.

The only problem is when I try and delete points that are newly created by clicking (not a part of the original dataset), I can only remove them **after** removing an original point and **only** in the reverse order they were created.  Very strange.

The example can be found here: https://codepen.io/seanlucano/pen/YzGaOox

Or see below:

```js
// set dimentions and margins of the plot 
const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// apend the g to HTML SVG '#plot" 
const svg = d3.select("#plot")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//add a target on plot to accept click event
const target = svg.append('rect')
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr("id", "target");

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seanlucano/interactive_data/main/MsftWlmrt.csv").then(data => {
    //parse string data to numeric
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.MsftReturn = +d.MsftReturn;
        d.WmtReturn = +d.WmtReturn;
    });
  
  // x scale
    let x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-10, 15])
      .range([0, width]);
    
    // x axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // y scale
    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-15, 15])
      .range([height, 0]);
    
    // y axis 
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  
  //caclulate regression data 
    const regression = d3.regressionLinear() // create a function generator
      .x(d => d.WmtReturn)   // set the x and y accessors (what columns to find data)
      .y(d => d.MsftReturn);
    const regressionLine = regression(data); //pass the data into the new function 

    // append regression line
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("x1", x(regressionLine[0][0]))
      .attr("y1", y(regressionLine[0][1]))
      .attr("x2", x(regressionLine[1][0]))
      .attr("y2", y(regressionLine[1][1]))
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("id", "regressionLine")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", .8);

    //add r value to the DOM
    d3.select("#R")
      .html(`R = ${Math.sqrt(regressionLine.rSquared).toFixed(3)}`);

    // create 'points' group element
    const points = svg.append('g')
        .attr("id", "points");
    
    //render circles in 'points' group element
    renderCircles();
  
  // INTERACTION

    // remove points on click
    currentCircles = d3.selectAll("circle")
        .on("click", function removePoint(event, d) {
          const e = currentCircles.nodes();
          const i = e.indexOf(this);
          console.log(i);
          data.splice(i,1);
          renderCircles();
          regressionUpdate();
        });

    // add points on click 
    target.on("click", function (event) {
      let coordsStart = d3.pointer(event, svg.node());
      let cx = coordsStart[0];
      let cy = coordsStart[1];
      
      let newData = {               //store click coords
        WmtReturn: x.invert(cx),
        MsftReturn: y.invert(cy)
      }
      
      data.push(newData);   //add new point coords to data
      renderCircles();      //render circles with updated data   
      regressionUpdate();   //update all regression logic
    });

// FUNCTIONS

    // render circles to plot
    function renderCircles() {
    
      const circles = points.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data);

      circles   
        .join("circle")
          .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.WmtReturn); })
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.MsftReturn); })
          //.attr("id", function (d,i) {return i;})
          .attr("r", 5)
          .style("fill", "#5c42ee")
          ;
    }

    // update regression data
    function regressionUpdate() {
  
        let regressionLine = regression(data); //calculate new regression line data

        d3.select("#regressionLine") //update the regression line with new data
          .attr("x1", x(regressionLine[0][0]))
          .attr("y1", y(regressionLine[0][1]))
          .attr("x2", x(regressionLine[1][0]))
          .attr("y2", y(regressionLine[1][1]));

        d3.select("#R") // update R value text node
        .html(`R = ${Math.sqrt(regressionLine.rSquared).toFixed(3)}`);
      }
});
```

```html
<div id="R"> R = -</div>
  
<svg id="plot"> </svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-regression@1.3.4/dist/d3-regression.min.js"></script>
```

Note: I'm using d3 v6 and the new selection.join() update method rather than the now deprecated enter, update, exit update pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The answer itself is relatively simple, but the behavior you are seeing is worth a dive into ("I can only remove them after removing an original point and only in the reverse order they were created.")

Let's take a look at the following workflow:

1. We append n circles,
2. We then select n circles and given them an event listener
3. We click on the chart to add a new node (the nᵗʰ+1 node)

Now we still have the original n circles, plus a new one. The original n have an event listener, so we can remove them, the new one doesn't, so we can't remove that one.

4. We click the chart again to add a new node (the nᵗʰ + 2 node)

This should be clear: we added another new node without an event listener.

5. We click on one of the original nodes to remove it.

We aren't actually removing the circle we click on, we remove that datum. Our data array is n+1 items long now, and we have n+2 circles until we run the render function.

When we do call the render function, we do a join. This join is based on index (as we don't provide an accessor for an datum id), so the first n items in the data array get attached to the first n circles. *ie: The iᵗʰ datum gets attached to the iᵗʰ circle.*

As the nᵗʰ+2 circle is no longer needed, it is removed.

The original n circles still remain, they have a listener that allows you to remove their bound datum from the data array. But, now the first node we added is now bound to the nth circle, so it can be removed. The second node we added still isn't one of the first n items in the data array, so it is bound to a circle with no event listener, waiting until another node leaves and it can be bound to the nᵗʰ circle.

This should explain how you needed to order your clicks to remove new data points.

*Conversely, if we remove all the circles, then add one, we cannot remove that circle - we removed all the circles with event listeners.*

Here's an example with a transition showing how the datums migrate between circles with every removal (well, more the circles migrate to the location specified by their new datum):

*Lighter circles have lower indexes, so their removal here will trigger more items in the data array being shifted and consequently bound to different circles. Circles with bound event listeners have a black outline*:

```js
// set dimentions and margins of the plot 
const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// apend the g to HTML SVG '#plot" 
const svg = d3.select("#plot")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//add a target on plot to accept click event
const target = svg.append('rect')
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr("id", "target");

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seanlucano/interactive_data/main/MsftWlmrt.csv").then(data => {
    //parse string data to numeric
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.MsftReturn = +d.MsftReturn;
        d.WmtReturn = +d.WmtReturn;
    });
  
  // x scale
    let x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-10, 15])
      .range([0, width]);
    
    // x axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // y scale
    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-15, 15])
      .range([height, 0]);
    
    // y axis 
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  
  //caclulate regression data 
    const regression = d3.regressionLinear() // create a function generator
      .x(d => d.WmtReturn)   // set the x and y accessors (what columns to find data)
      .y(d => d.MsftReturn);
    const regressionLine = regression(data); //pass the data into the new function 

    // append regression line
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("x1", x(regressionLine[0][0]))
      .attr("y1", y(regressionLine[0][1]))
      .attr("x2", x(regressionLine[1][0]))
      .attr("y2", y(regressionLine[1][1]))
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("id", "regressionLine")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", .8)
      

    //add r value to the DOM
    d3.select("#R")
      .html(`R = ${Math.sqrt(regressionLine.rSquared).toFixed(3)}`);

    // create 'points' group element
    const points = svg.append('g')
        .attr("id", "points");
    
    //render circles in 'points' group element
    renderCircles();
  
  // INTERACTION

    // remove points on click
    currentCircles = d3.selectAll("circle")
        .on("click", function removePoint(event, d) {
          const e = currentCircles.nodes();
          const i = e.indexOf(this);
          console.log(i);
          data.splice(i,1);
          renderCircles();
          regressionUpdate();
        })
        .attr("stroke","black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);

    // add points on click 
    target.on("click", function (event) {
      let coordsStart = d3.pointer(event, svg.node());
      let cx = coordsStart[0];
      let cy = coordsStart[1];
      
      let newData = {               //store click coords
        WmtReturn: x.invert(cx),
        MsftReturn: y.invert(cy)
      }
      
      data.push(newData);   //add new point coords to data
      renderCircles();      //render circles with updated data   
      regressionUpdate();   //update all regression logic
    });

// FUNCTIONS

    // render circles to plot
    function renderCircles() {
    
      const circles = points.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data);

      var color = d3.scaleLinear()
       .domain([0,60])
       .range(["#eeeeee","steelblue"])

      circles   
        .join("circle")
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.WmtReturn); })
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.MsftReturn); })
          .attr("r", 8)
          .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i)  })
          ;
    }

    // update regression data
    function regressionUpdate() {
  
        let regressionLine = regression(data); //calculate new regression line data

        d3.select("#regressionLine") //update the regression line with new data
          .attr("x1", x(regressionLine[0][0]))
          .attr("y1", y(regressionLine[0][1]))
          .attr("x2", x(regressionLine[1][0]))
          .attr("y2", y(regressionLine[1][1]));

        d3.select("#R") // update R value text node
        .html(`R = ${Math.sqrt(regressionLine.rSquared).toFixed(3)}`);
      }
});
```

```html
<div id="R"> R = -</div>
  
<svg id="plot"> </svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-regression@1.3.4/dist/d3-regression.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution**

The solution is relatively trivial, take your currentCircle code an place it in the render function so it runs every time and all circles have an event listener:

```js
// set dimentions and margins of the plot 
const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// apend the g to HTML SVG '#plot" 
const svg = d3.select("#plot")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//add a target on plot to accept click event
const target = svg.append('rect')
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr("id", "target");

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seanlucano/interactive_data/main/MsftWlmrt.csv").then(data => {
    //parse string data to numeric
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.MsftReturn = +d.MsftReturn;
        d.WmtReturn = +d.WmtReturn;
    });
  
  // x scale
    let x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-10, 15])
      .range([0, width]);
    
    // x axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // y scale
    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-15, 15])
      .range([height, 0]);
    
    // y axis 
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  
  //caclulate regression data 
    const regression = d3.regressionLinear() // create a function generator
      .x(d => d.WmtReturn)   // set the x and y accessors (what columns to find data)
      .y(d => d.MsftReturn);
    const regressionLine = regression(data); //pass the data into the new function 

    // append regression line
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("x1", x(regressionLine[0][0]))
      .attr("y1", y(regressionLine[0][1]))
      .attr("x2", x(regressionLine[1][0]))
      .attr("y2", y(regressionLine[1][1]))
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("id", "regressionLine")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", .8);

    //add r value to the DOM
    d3.select("#R")
      .html(`R = ${Math.sqrt(regressionLine.rSquared).toFixed(3)}`);

    // create 'points' group element
    const points = svg.append('g')
        .attr("id", "points");
    
    //render circles in 'points' group element
    renderCircles();
  
  // INTERACTION


    // add points on click 
    target.on("click", function (event) {
      let coordsStart = d3.pointer(event, svg.node());
      let cx = coordsStart[0];
      let cy = coordsStart[1];
      
      let newData = {               //store click coords
        WmtReturn: x.invert(cx),
        MsftReturn: y.invert(cy)
      }
      
      data.push(newData);   //add new point coords to data
      renderCircles();      //render circles with updated data   
      regressionUpdate();   //update all regression logic
    });

// FUNCTIONS

    // render circles to plot
    function renderCircles() {
    
      const circles = points.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data);

      circles   
        .join("circle")
          .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.WmtReturn); })
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.MsftReturn); })
          //.attr("id", function (d,i) {return i;})
          .attr("r", 5)
          .style("fill", "#5c42ee")
          ;
          

    // remove points on click
    currentCircles = d3.selectAll("circle")
        .on("click", function removePoint(event, d) {
          const e = currentCircles.nodes();
          const i = e.indexOf(this);
          console.log(i);
          data.splice(i,1);
          renderCircles();
          regressionUpdate();
        });          
          
    }

    // update regression data
    function regressionUpdate() {
  
        let regressionLine = regression(data); //calculate new regression line data

        d3.select("#regressionLine") //update the regression line with new data
          .attr("x1", x(regressionLine[0][0]))
          .attr("y1", y(regressionLine[0][1]))
          .attr("x2", x(regressionLine[1][0]))
          .attr("y2", y(regressionLine[1][1]));

        d3.select("#R") // update R value text node
        .html(`R = ${Math.sqrt(regressionLine.rSquared).toFixed(3)}`);
      }
});
```

```html
<div id="R"> R = -</div>
  
<svg id="plot"> </svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-regression@1.3.4/dist/d3-regression.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Incredible answer.  Thank you so much. Clearly need to get a better understanding of event listeners in these situations.